# Compare array items

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison

I got array (someObjects) of some objects (someObject) with two properties - number and date. I want to compare all objects in array with each others. If in array exist object with smaller number and latest date than other objects - I need to return "not ok".

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of your array and an example of what you want the result to be (and anything you've tried).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterFunc = (a, _, array) => {
  return (array.some(el => el.number > a.number) && array.some(el => el.date < a.date));
};
const isNotOk = array => {
  if (array.some(filterFunc)) console.log("not ok");
};

const someObjects = [{ number: 42, date: new Date(999999999999) }, { number: 7, date: new Date(555555555555) }];
const someObjects2 = [{ number: 1, date: new Date(999999999999) }, { number: 7, date: new Date(555555555555) }];

isNotOk(someObjects); // prints "not Ok"
isNotOk(someObjects2); // does nothing
```